# r - read.xlsx from .xlsx with unknown number of sheets

Tags: r, excel, for-loop, r-xlsx

Suppose I have an excel file, which I would like to read to R with `read.xlsx` function. File consists of spreadsheets, number of which I do not know (there is like 200 of such files so manually checking number of sheets would be huge pain). Each spreadsheet is organized like a proper data frame.
I would like to have those spreadsheets one on top of another.
I write something like:

```
    columnsILike <- c(1,40)
    for(i in 1:numberOfSheets){
        dfInd <- read.xlsx("myfile.xlsx", i, # number of sheet
                           colIndex=columnsILike, endRow=201, startRow=2, 
                           header=F)
        PreviousEmptyDataFrame <- rbind(PreviousEmptyDataFrame, dfInd)
    }
    write.csv(PreviousEmptyDataFrame, "data.csv")
```

Question is, how do I know number of sheets in advance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getSheets(loadWorkbook("file_path"))` in the [XLSX package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf) should return a list of the sheets in the workbook so you can get the length of the list to find the amount of sheets.

Comment: Just my opinion, but I like this solution less, as xlsx requires a java installation. I like the lightest solution possible, and thus prefer the gdata answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is rather late, but wouldn't this be simpler?

`gdata::sheetCount("myworkbook.xlsx")`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use package `XLConnect` if the workbook isn't too large.

```
library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("myworkbook.xlsx")
result <- do.call(rbind,lapply(getSheets(wb),
                               function(sheet)readWorksheet(wb,sheet)))
```